# Removing trailing empty elements in a list

Tags: python, list

Is there an elegant pythonic way of removing trailing empty elements from a list?  A sort of `list.rstrip(None)`. So

```
[1, 2, 3, None, 4, None, None]
```

should result in

```
[1, 2, 3, None, 4]
```

I guess this could be generalized to removing trailing elements of any particular value.

If possible, I would like to have this done as a single line (readable) expression

Answer (score 22):

If you want to get rid of only `None` values and leave zeros or other falsy values, you could do:

```
while my_list and my_list[-1] is None:
    my_list.pop()
```

To remove all falsy values (zeros, empty strings, empty lists, etc.) you can do:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, None, 4, None, None]
while not my_list[-1]:
    my_list.pop()
print(my_list)
# [1, 2, 3, None, 4]
```

Comment: The second code fails for a list full of falsy values, including `[None]`, `[None, None]`, `[0, '', []]`, etc. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10034995/7851470) addresses this issue.

Answer (score 9):

The following explicitly checks for `None` elements:

```
while l and l[-1] is None:
    l.pop()
```

It can be generalized as follows:

```
f = lambda x: x is None
while l and f(l[-1]):
    l.pop()
```

You can now define different functions for `f` to check for other conditions.

Answer (score 5):

```
def remove_trailing(l, remove_value=None):
    i = len(l)
    while i > 0 and l[i - 1] == remove_value:
        i -= 1
    return l[:i]
```

Comment: This is the best answer by far. Another variation would be an in-place slice assignment instead of returning the slice to preserve command/query separation. If you're into that. This is a nice functional style.

Comment: @aaronasterling I like this solution as well. I'm trying to learn more about functional style. What do you mean by __in-place slice assignment__. Just assigning the slice back to the `l` parameter? And not returning it? (Surely not that)

Comment: @alan, instead of `return l[:i]`, it would be `l[:] = l[:i]`. That makes it a command in that it would change the state of `l`. I was off base in that it's currently a query (returns data and doesn't change state) so that it does preserve command query separation. I was picturing using it like `l = remove_trailing(l)` and _that_ would violate CQ separation, _imo_. I'm probably being overly pedantic here.

Comment: A great answer (+1), not least because it is generic in what is to be removed (in my case, empty strings at the end of a text list)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
>>> x=[1, 2, 3, None, 4, None, None]
>>> while x[-1] is None:
    x.pop()
```

Comment: your answer is like the alan's answer, you can add a vote to his answer instead issuing a new answer.

Comment: @pylover: alan's answer creates unnecessary copies. He should have used pop instead.

Answer (score 1):

For a one-line solution:

```
In [30]: from itertools import dropwhile

In [31]: list(reversed(tuple(dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, reversed([1, 2, 3, None, 4, None, None])))))
Out[31]: [1, 2, 3, None, 4]
```

If you want to reuse it, here's a definition in point-free style:

```
In [36]: from functional import compose, partial

In [37]: varargs = lambda *args: args

In [38]: compose_mult = compose(partial(reduce, compose),varargs) # compose which takes variable number of arguments. Innermost function to the right.

In [39]: compose_mult(list, reversed, tuple, partial(dropwhile, lambda x: x is None), reversed)([1, 2, 3, None, 4, None, None])
Out[39]: [1, 2, 3, None, 4]
```

Comment: It works but it sacrifices readability too much in my opinion.

Comment: @SimeonVisser That's a matter of opinion, but yes, I'm not crazy about the need to force to a tuple in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I never accepted an answer because I wasn't really happy with solutions offered.  Here's another solution (1 line and no library dependencies) that I'm not entirely happy with either:

```
a = [1, 2, None, 3, None, None]
reduce(lambda l, e: [e]+l if l or e is not None else [], reversed(a), [])
```

Comment: It would be nice if https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip existed for lists.   But since it doesn't, alan's two-line pop loop works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an one-liner, it could be like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, None, 4, None, None]
b = [x for n, x in enumerate(a) if any(y is not None for y in a[n:])]
print b
```

Note that it's quadratic (in the worst case).

For any falsy value, it's even simpler:

```
b = [x for n, x in enumerate(a) if any(a[n:])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to compromise readability here is what I'd do.

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> l=[1,2,3,None,4,5,None,None]
>>> l[:-len(list(takewhile(lambda x: x==None, reversed(l))))]
[1,2,3,None,4,5]
```

Comment: It appears from your output that this achieves nothing.

Comment: I copy pasted the wrong line, it instead achieves the correct result and I bet faster than many other solutions

Answer (score 0):

The [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) project implements `rstrip` for any iterable:

```
iterable = [1, 2, 3, None, 4, None, None]
list(mit.rstrip(iterable, lambda x: x in {None}))
# [1, 2, 3, None, 4]
```

`more_itertools.rstrip` accepts an iterable and predicate.  See the [source code](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.py#L1361) for details.

Answer (score -1):

Here's yet another one-liner:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, None, 4, None, None]
>>> [l[i] for i in range(len("".join(map(lambda x: {None: " "}.get(x, "_"), l)).rstrip()))]
[1, 2, 3, None, 4]
```

These things are fun!

**EDIT**

I just realized that the list comprehension is completely unnecessary. Slicing should work just fine:

```
>>> l[:len("".join(map(lambda x: {None: " "}.get(x, "_"), l)).rstrip())]
```

Comment: And it makes use of `rstrip()`, albeit in a very roundabout way.

Answer (score -1):

What about recursion + slicing?

```
>>> rstrip = lambda x, elts=(None,): rstrip(x[:-1], elts) if x and x[-1] in elts else x
>>> rstrip([1, 2, 3, None])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> rstrip([1, 2, 3, None], (None, 3))
[1, 2]
```

Note: I'm assuming that you're not looking for the most computationally efficient solution here...

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
[a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i:] != [None] * (len(a) - i) ]
```